# cannot understand the ouput of this for() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
transposed = []
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]

for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    transpose_row = []
    for row in matrix:
        transpose_row.append(row[i])
        transposed.append(transpose_row)
```

the output is `[[1, 4], [1, 4], [2, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 7]]`.
but in the second `for` 1 is firstly added in the `transpose_row`, and then 4 is added too, which means, that **[1]** is at the first time added and **[1, 4]** at the second time added to the list `transposed`. So the output confuses me.

Comment: you append the same list twice. So changing the first affects the other. See it with a quick example: `l = []; a = [l, l]; l.append(1)` and now print `a`

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: but at the first time `transposed` is `[[1]]`. At the second round [1,4] is added to `[[1]]`

Comment: i see. at the first round `transpose_row`  contain`[1]`, but in the seond time`[4]`is added to `transpose_row`, so the `transpose` of the first round contain now `[1,4]`

Comment: it's more than that. the first two elements of `transposed` refer to the same object! but yeah, i think you got the point